# Snow Leopard Cubase 5 with Parallels broken sound

Tags: audio, parallels

using snow leopard, I'm trying to run cubase 5 on parallels and the sound is really broken.
If I play songs on youtube or anything else the sound is perfect.

my sound card is motu ultralite.

I tried installing asio4all but with it I can't even pick audio outputs.

any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had this problem running Cubase 4 Essential. Go into Devices/Device Setup/Control Panel
and set the output buffer to at least 4096 and change the sync reference to Direct Sound Output.

Hope that helps!